# Read file contents with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to read the contents of a file line by line with Laravel.
However, I can't seem to find anything about it anywhere.

Should I use the fopen function or can I do it with the File::get() function?

I've checked the API but there doesn't seem to have a function to read the contents of the file.

Comment: There aren't any native methods / functions in Laravel that will do this. Look to grabbing a package that handles files or as you've started doing, do it yourself manually.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was something since you can get the file with File::get($path). I'll develop my own methods then!

Comment: I thought that too when I had this problem a while back. Unfortunately the `File::get()` method uses `file_get_contents()` to return the entire contents of a file.

Answer (score 35):

You can use simple PHP:

```
foreach(file('yourfile.txt') as $line) {
    // loop with $line for each line of yourfile.txt
}
```

Comment: That's what I am doing, I was just wondering if there's a Laravel function to do this.

Comment: How Laravel could do shorter than 1 line?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `file()` returns the contents of the file as an array. `File::get` and `file_get_contents` both return the contents as a string, which you then need to parse over a delimiter to get into an array.

Answer (score 27):

You can use the following to get the contents:

```
$content = File::get($filename);
```

Which will return a `Illuminate\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException` if it's not found. If you want to fetch something remote you can use:

```
$content = File::getRemote($url);
```

Which will return `false` if not found.

When you have the file you don't need laravel specific methods for handling the data. Now you need to work with the content in php. If you wan't to read the lines you can do it like @kylek described:

```
 foreach($content as $line) {
    //use $line 
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me because, as Victor pointed out, the $content will contain a string, not an array. I get an "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" when I try this.

Comment: just use the answer above and do the initial file read with file()

Comment: I have used $content = File::get($filename);  and getting error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\File::get().

Comment: @Pax the correct class for `File` is `Illuminate\Support\Facades\File` but you need to use the `Storage` with Laravel 7+

Comment: Use `explode(PHP_EOL, $content)` to get the content in an array of lines

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
try
{
    $contents = File::get($filename);
}
catch (Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException $exception)
{
    die("The file doesn't exist");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**you can do something like this:**

```
$file = '/home/albert/myfile.txt';//the path of your file
$conn = Storage::disk('my_disk');//configured in the file filesystems.php
$stream = $conn->readStream($file);
while (($line = fgets($stream, 4096)) !== false) {
   //$line is the string var of your line from your file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use**

```
 file_get_contents(base_path('app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php'), true);
```

Comment: I am sure you **don't** want to have any method that reads your development files (especially Controllers) from your server exposed to the client in anyway, no matter how secure the read access is. This a huge security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel V 10.10 confirmed working

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::lines(storage_path('app/whatever.txt'))->each(function ($line) {
    $this->info($line);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$tmpName = $request->file('csv_file');
$csvAsArray = array_map('str_getcsv', file($tmpName));
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.