# How to properly give a path to open a file in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, file

I was following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730861/read-file-contents-with-laravel) about file system in laravel.
I am running version 5.4 inside ubuntu 16.10.

This is what I have inside my controller - only for test:

```
    use File;
    ...

public function dbIni() { 
    $filename="../../../storage/brUf";
            $content = File::get($filename);
            foreach($content as $line) {
                echo $line;
            }
}
```

Inside storage I have a  **brUf** file.

When I try to run this code this is what I get:

```
FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 41:
File does not exist at path ../../../storage/brUf
```

What am I missing for this path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use laravel's helper function called `storage_path()`

so

```
public function dbIni() { 
$filename=storage_path("brUf");
        $content = File::get($filename);
        foreach($content as $line) {
            echo $line;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Almazik I got this error ErrorException in TestDbController.php line 21:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). In the error I can see the file content. But for some reason it is not being displayed. Any idea?

Comment: at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()', '/home/ila/vhosts/drefapi.com/app/Http/Controllers/TestDbController.php', 23, array('filename' => '/home/ila/vhosts/drefapi.com/storage/brUf', 'content' => ' .... real content'

Comment: @zwitterion after line `$content = File::get($filename);` dump what you have in the this variable: `dd($content);`