# Retrieving a json file stored in storage folder

Tags: laravel-5.3

How can I retrieve a json file which stored in a folder?. File path is: `"storage/app/public/Upload"`

I wrote something like this:

```
$Content=storage_path('app\public\Upload')::get('outstanding.json');
dd($Content);
```

but it is wrong.

Comment: How do you know it is wrong? Do you have an error? Does it have an output? What is it?

Comment: Yes, i am getting a FatalThrowableError

Comment: Can you edit your question and post all information regarding the error?

Comment: under fatalthrowable error , i can see like this ..  Class D:\www\mit\laravel\storage\app\public\Upload' not found

Comment: It looks like your file path does not exist. Can you double check in the console with `DIR` if your path exists?

Comment: Erase all, and please tell me how to read a file from a folder, my file path is: storage/app/public/Upload.  I don't know as I am new to the laravel :(

Comment: That question has already been asked and well answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730861/read-file-contents-with-laravel